# Mockito exceptions in stubbed method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

If I have a function a() that can throw exceptions, and I want to mock it.
If I write

```
Mockito.when(a()).callRealMethod()
```

the compiler tells me to add try-catch block or to add the throw declerations.
But I don't want to call the method a() in that line, I just want to make sure that when I call the method somewhere later in the test, it will call the real method, and then I will add try-catch.
How to do it?

Comment: That's a limitation of the language. You'll need to deal with the exception (that will not get thrown).

Comment: What is more correct (in a manner of conventions) of dealing with exceptions in a test, in case no exception should be thrown? to add try-catch block and in the catch put fail()? Or to add throw declaration to the signature?

Comment: Just add the `throws` to the method. If an exception IS thrown, then the test will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to add a `throws Exception` note to all test methods, as the framework will automatically fail the test if any unexpected exception is thrown. This allows you to call/mock any method that throws an Exception without explicitly writing error-handling code.

For JUnit:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class YourTest {
  @Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // ...
  }

  @Test public void fooShouldDoBar() throws Exception {
    // ...
  }
}
```